# invalid conversion from 'void (*)()' to 'void*' (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, implicit-conversion, void-pointers

I was learning about generic pointer `void*`, that allows you to store addresses of multiple data types. However, when trying to store the address of a function, I need to cast it, eg:

`ptr = (void*)someFunc`

while for primitive data types, I don't need the cast:

`ptr = &a`

Where `ptr` here is a `void*` pointer.

Why does this happen?

```
void someFunc(){
    cout << ("hello");
}

int main(){
    int a = 5;
    string b = "Hello boiii";

    void* ptr = &a;

    cout << "ptr holding address of variable a of type int" << endl;
    cout << ptr << endl;

    ptr = &b;
    cout << "ptr holding address of variable b of object string" << endl;
    cout << ptr << endl;

    ptr = (void*)someFunc; // doubt
    cout << "ptr holding address of function someFunc" << endl;
    cout << ptr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a function is not a data type, it is a function type.

Comment: Side note: Use `void*` with caution. It's hard to reason about an object when you've remove its type. Most of the time in C++ you can avoid `void*` completely with a template, base class, or specialized wrapper like `std::variant`.

Comment: To be explicit - C++ does not guarantee that a pointer to data (`void*`) is capable of holding a pointer to a function.  Your C-style casts force the code to compile whether or not it's successful.

Answer (score 3):

You may not assign a pointer of the type `c/v void *` with a function pointer, provided that the implementation does not conditionally supports such a conversion. You can only assign a pointer of the type `c/v void *` with a pointer to object.

From the C++ 14 Standard (4.10 Pointer conversions)

> 2 A prvalue of type “pointer to cv T,” where T is an object type, can
> be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv void”. The result of
> converting a non-null pointer value of a pointer to object type to a
> “pointer to cv void” represents the address of the same byte in memory
> as the original pointer value. The null pointer value is converted to
> the null pointer value of the destination type.

and

> 8 Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice
> versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is
> implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports
> conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to
> the other type and back, possibly with different cvqualification,
> shall yield the original pointer value.

And from the C Standard (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
> object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a
> pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the
> original pointer.
>
> 8 A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to
> a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
> equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call
> a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the
> behavior is undefined.

Comment: That's not actually correct, the Standard says that conversions between object pointers and function pointers are "conditionally supported".

Answer (score 3):

This is the actual rule in the Standard that govern interchangeability and conversion between function pointers (including `void(*)(void)` and object pointers (such as `void*`):

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is
> implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with different cv-qualification, shall yield the original pointer value.

https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8

This means that on some platforms, the conversion may be outright rejected (for example some architectures hold code and data in different memory spaces and require differently-sized pointers for each), while on platforms where it is possible, the conversion is likely to generate a portability warning if you have such warnings enabled.

POSIX makes some additional guarantees in order to support dynamic loading -- `dlsym`'s return value may be either an object or function pointer, so conversion between them has to be possible on POSIX platforms.